# Flat positive sinus when simulating on Multisim

Tags: ltspice, multisim

I am a biomedical engineering student and I have a recurring problem on Multisim.

When I try to redo my LTspice circuit I end up with a flat positive sinus. I tried changing the values to see if there is something wrong with the circuit itself but still always the same flat sinus on the positive side.

[image]

[image]
[image]

It looks like I made a  fatal error but I can't see where it is exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will always happen with BJT amplifiers like this when trying to drive high-level signals to the output. The gain of the amplifier changes with the collector voltage. So, when the peak of the sinewave at the collector occurs, gain is slightly less than when the trough of the sinewave is at the collector. This happens because the internal emitter resistance (inside the transistor) increases when collector current lowers and, that resistance adds to the external emitter resistor that is supposed to define the amplification.

So, with a high voltage peak at the collector, collector current is lower than when there is a low voltage trough at the collector. The internal emitter resistance in ohms is defined by this equation: -

$$r_E = \dfrac{25\text{ (mV)}}{I_C\text{ (mA)}}$$

So, if you work out what the instantaneous collector current is when the voltage is maximum at the collector AND, do the same when the voltage is minimum at the collector, you will get several mA difference. That difference causes \$r_E\$ to change and add to the 80.6 Ω resistor in the emitter that defines the gain.

Result: the sinewave looks flatter at the top compared to the bottom

Comment: Yeah the Issue was with my source and fixed it.  But now the exact circut gives me a lower voltage on the multisim. Output in Spice is 3,12 V and 2,896 in  multisim. I consolted a friend as well but he doesnt know we checked every part of the circuit and it is exactly the same. any ideas?

Comment: It could literally be the difference between transistor models @MohammedJacob also, R5 and Rc should be the same value but they aren't.

Comment: I fixed R5 and RC and now they are the same. and  I am using the transistor 2N3904 for both

Comment: You need to look at model differences. For instance trying different transistors within LTSpice will indicate how much variation there can be despite the circuit trying to produce stable values. Things like this happen between transistors from the same batch in reality and what you have is, in fact a +/- 4% variation about a mean value of 3.00 volts. Not really a lot @MohammedJacob

Answer (score 1):

I see that \$R_C\$ (LTspice) and \$R5\$ (Multisim) have different values.  \$C3\$ (LTspice) and \$C2\$ (Multisim) also have different values.

I think the real problem lies in the signal generators, though.

In LTspice, the signal level is given as 0.1V while in Multisim the signal generator (the green trace) appears to be at something like 2V peak to peak.  You are most likely over driving the input and causing distortion.